# openvpn-install script with parameters

Tags: php, linux, bash, openvpn, phpseclib

Hey I am trying to create openvpn clients using the following script https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install from my webserver.

I have properly configured an SSH2 API that I can use to send commands to my linux server.

I also can verify that the script works.

I just don't know how to run the script with 2 parameters in a single command.

I have tried executing the parameters line by line to no avail;

```
echo $ssh->exec("bash openvpn-install.sh");
echo $ssh->exec("1");
echo $ssh->exec("randomid12345");
```

I have also tried the command `bash openvpn-install.sh 1 12356`

As well as `bash openvpn-install.sh -1 -12356`

But that did not work either.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: how about echo $ssh->exec('openvpn-install.sh 1 12356');

Comment: "I have also tried the command bash openvpn-install.sh 1 12356" 

I have tried running that command as shown in the OP straight from the command line, how would it be different if I ran it from my PHP script?

Comment: what about adding ./openvpn-install.sh 1 12356 or sh openvpn-install.sh 1 12356

Comment: The second command started doing some weird stuff so I cancelled the operation.

Comment: root@vps36347:~# sh openvpn-install.sh 1 12356
openvpn-install.sh: 9: openvpn-install.sh: [[: not found
openvpn-install.sh: 15: openvpn-install.sh: [[: not found
openvpn-install.sh: 21: openvpn-install.sh: [[: not found
openvpn-install.sh: 48: openvpn-install.sh: [[: not found
openvpn-install.sh: 53: openvpn-install.sh: [[: not found

Comment: i think you need to add the path of openvpn-install.sh when calling it.

Comment: Why I am calling it from the directory it is in, but I will try anyway

Comment: Same output it did some weird stuff

Comment: Command ran was sh /root/openvpn-install.sh 1 12356

Comment: Still looking for help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
echo $ssh->exec("bash openvpn-install.sh");
echo $ssh->exec("1");
echo $ssh->exec("randomid12345");
```

What about this?:

```
$ssh->write("bash openvpn-install.sh\n");
echo $ssh->read('[whatever]');
$ssh->write("1\n");
echo $ssh->read('[whatever]');
$ssh->write("randomid12345\n");
echo $ssh->read('[whatever]');
```

Comment: I'll try it!

Thanks for the help, I will post shortly

Comment: Still not working my friend

Comment: Please help, I really need this simple issue solved.

Comment: You do realize that `[whatever]` is a placeholder, don't you? Looking at the openvpn-install.sh script you linked to it looks like the first `[whatever]` needs to be `Select an option [1-4]:`. I'll let you figure out what the second and third ones need to be. A quick tip. If you don't know what the prompt is you can do `$ssh->setTimeout(2)` or something and then do `$ssh->read()` and just have it return everything that's available up to that point.

Comment: Thank you neubert for the response, I will try that now

Comment: $ssh->setTimeout(2);

$ssh->write("bash openvpn-install.sh\n");
$ssh->read();
$ssh->write("1\n");
$ssh->read();
$ssh->write("randomid1586\n");

Seems to be working, for the random id, it auto places client, so the output would be clientrandomid1586 how can I remove the client part

Comment: Well in the code snippet you posted there's no output. There's no print or echo. Can you post the actual code snippet you're using? Also, personally, I'd do `$ssh->read('Select an option [1-4]:')` etc instead of `$ssh->setTimeout(2); $ssh->read()`. Waiting two seconds is unnecessary.

Comment: Why does it have to "read" I am not sure

Comment: read() returns the output as a string. If you're wanting to output anything you'll have to read(). If all you want to do is send a command read() might still be useful. ie. you could do `$ssh->write(), $ssh->setTimeout(2); $ssh->write()` but then you'd be waiting 2 seconds when you might only need to wait 0.1 seconds. Basically, some amount of waiting could very well be necessary (eg. you can't send a new command to the shell before the prompt appears) but no need to wait longer than you need to.

Comment: Thank you for the help I will just use the wait for now, I selected your answer for all of the diligent help!